# Flow module not found with .scss file

Tags: sass, webpack, flowtype, css-modules

I have a file using scss with css-modules like so:

`import styles from './Login.scss';`

The webpack build works fine but i'm getting a flow error: `Required Module Not Found`

In my .flowconfig I have

```
[ignore]
.*/node_modules/fbjs/.*
.*/app/main.js
.*/app/dist/.*
.*/release/.*
.*/git/.*

[include]

[libs]

[options]
esproposal.class_static_fields=enable
esproposal.class_instance_fields=enable
esproposal.export_star_as=enable
module.name_mapper.extension='css' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/flow/CSSModule.js.flow'
module.name_mapper.extension='styl' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/flow/CSSModule.js.flow'
module.name_mapper.extension='png' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/flow/WebpackAsset.js.flow'
module.name_mapper.extension='jpg' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/flow/WebpackAsset.js.flow'
suppress_comment=\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\$FlowFixMe
suppress_comment=\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\$FlowIssue
```

I've also seen https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/338 but it doesn't really have any solution.

Has anyone found a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error can be fixed by assigning .scss files to an empty module. I just npm installed empty and added this to the .flowconfig :
`module.name_mapper.extension='scss' -> 'empty/object'`

Comment: but what about imported files without extensions?

Answer (score 24):

A better solution for this error is to use the [css-modules-flow-types](https://github.com/skovhus/css-modules-flow-types) webpack plugin to generate flow types for your CSS modules.

Flow doesn't know about the `scss` extension, so you need to add the following to your `.flowconfig`, in the `[options]` section:

```
; Extensions
module.file_ext=.js
module.file_ext=.jsx
module.file_ext=.json
module.file_ext=.css
module.file_ext=.scss
```

You should also add `*.scss.flow` to your `.gitignore`. These files shouldn't be checked in because they are automatically generated during the webpack build.

Answer (score 9):

added all the file types I wanted flow to recognize in .flowconfig file

```
[options]    
module.file_ext=.js
module.file_ext=.json
module.file_ext=.jsx
module.file_ext=.css
module.file_ext=.scss
```

Answer (score 5):

We can use [module.name_mapper.extension](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-module-name-mapper-extension-string-string) to replace types for imported module on `Object`

> module.name_mapper.extension - Specify a file extension to match, and a replacement module name,
>   separated by a ->.

add option to `.flowconfig` file

```
// .flowconfig
[options]
module.name_mapper.extension='scss' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/flowconfig.mock-module.js'
```

create new file

```
// flowconfig.mock-module.js
export default Object;
```